# Can't call a external view function with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, frontend

I need to call a getter function from my contract, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0xc3a8b1710c15f6ba59f9fefea5d9da656aabb8495834fb56c9b4277df741d610": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 305,
      "return": "0x"
    },
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganach04KHEZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at /tmp/.mount_ganach04KHEZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:568:26",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
}
    at Object._fireError (index.js:50)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:540)
    at cb (util.js:689)
    at callbackifyOnRejected (util.js:666)
    at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123)
```

My contract version is ^0.8.0 and the code related to the function is:

```
ItemForSale[] public itemsForSale;
function totalItemsForSale() external view returns(uint256) {
    return itemsForSale.length;
  }
```

My attempt to call the function from the front-end using web3 is:

```
const totalItemsForSale = await marketplaceContract.methods.totalItemsForSale().call();
```

Comment: DId you try any other methods?

Comment: Are you using the correct artifacts for the contract? Do you use truffle or hardhat? What network are you using? How is the struct ItemForSale declared? Could you, please, provide more Solidity code?

Comment: I just found the problem. I was passing the address from the other contract to the MarketplaceContract.

Comment: @NatalieBravo Can you add that as answer so the question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. I was passing the address from the other contract to the MarketplaceContract. A silly mistake.